# Use mvn to create rpm that lists dependencies rather than including them

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm looking to package my Java application as an RPM that lists transitive dependencies (as RPM dependencies) rather than packaging them into the RPM itself. I understand how to use the mvn-rpm plugin to build an rpm that collects all dependencies into a single deployable artifact.  What I'm hoping to do though is to just translate the declared dependencies in a mvn pom file into declared dependencies in an rpm.  Then a particular mvn module will create its own rpm that includes just its own jar plus the list of dependencies it requires.  I will then build separate RPMs that can provide those dependencies.  The ultimate goal is to have a kind of composeable application architecture deployable as RPMs.